# $state are not workig angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, state, rootscope, angularjs-rootscope

I have 2 pages and I want to pass a variable from page 1 to page 2.

**page1.html**

```
<ion-view ion-title="Home">
<ion-content>
    <label class="item item-input">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a value" ng-model="value">
    </label>

    <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="me(value)" >
    Go to List
    </button>

</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

this is the **controller** , I use $state to go to page 2 and I use $rootscope  to be able to use the value in the page2Controller

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('page1Ctrl', function($rootScope ,$state ) {

    $rootScope.me = function(value)
    {
        $rootScope.value= value;
        $state.go('page2');
    };

});
```

the problem is , when I click the button in page 1 
it doesn't take me to page2
where is the mistake

this is states code

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
$stateProvider  
.state('page1', {
    url: '/page1',
    templateUrl: 'templates/page1.html',    controller: 'page1Ctrl'})   

.state('page2', {
    url: '/page2',  
    templateUrl: 'templates/page2.html',    controller: 'page2Ctrl'})

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/page1');})
```

Comment: where is the code for your `$state` definitions?

Comment: don't paste code in comments;  it can't be formatted or read easily.  you should [edit] your question instead.

Comment: I did it , thank you

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Answer (score 3):

You did not add dependency to

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ui.router'])
.controller('page1Ctrl', function($rootScope ,$state ) {

    $rootScope.me = function(value)
    {
        $rootScope.value= value;
        $state.go('page2');
    };
});
```

and reference the js file in your html file.

or

In case of **ionic framework** I would suggest you to go with **ion-nav-view** in this [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/) which will reduce your efforts to a greater extent, where your module is dependent on **ionic** as below

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
```

Comment: It's possible OP has a separate main module (guessing it's called "starter") and it does include `ui.router`. This is still good advice though as module's should be stand-alone and include all required dependencies

Comment: Yes but no where in the code, there is a dependency to **ionic**.
Thank you Phil. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Depends, OP hasn't shown the module declaration for that `config` function. You may very well be correct but it's impossible to tell until OP comes back and adds more information

Comment: Yes. Exactly Correct.